# Jquery JSON return append to query string

Tags: jquery, json, append

How can i append JSON callback `proj` as query string?

```
success: function(response){
        window.proj = '?proj='+response.proj;
        alert(proj);
}
```

it's need to be insert right after `export.php?proj=project-name`

```
<button type="button" onClick="parent.location='export.php'">Submit</button>
```

Would it be possible?

Answer (score 0):

The decodeURIComponent function searches the given string for escape sequences and replaces them with the actual character.

```
success: function(response){
        window.proj = '?proj='+response.proj;
        //If data is your object with key value pair of names and values
        var data = { first_parameter: 'first', second_parameter: 'second' };
        var queryStringparams = decodeURIComponent($.param(data));
        //End
        alert(proj);
}
```